# Customizing ChangePassword template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Is there a way to customize `<asp:ChangePassword>` control to show fields for security question and answer as well? The default control can read **UserName** and **Old Password** without writing any code, probably through the control IDs?! I tried doing the same by adding a couple more TextBoxes to the template, but it doesn't appear to load those values from the database.

I'm using SQL Server as Membership Provider if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered that `ChangePassword` control is not designed for this purpose. To reset/retrieve your password using security Question/Answer, ASP.NET provides `PasswordRecovery` control. May help someone else in the future.